# Angular JS splitting a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would I split a string like the one below:

```
str = "[[a,b] , [c,d] , [e,f] , [g,h]]"
```

Now, what I want is an array with 4 elements:

```
[a,b] [c,d] [e,f] [g,h]
```

If i use the split function with str.split(","), then I think the array would not be split as I want. Also, I later want to iterate on values of a and b and c and d separately. Is there a way of doing that quickly and in short?

Comment: [`JSON.parse(str.replace(/(\w+)/g, '"$1"'))`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/84Lo6yd6/)

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the issue comment, you can escape the whole string and then parse it as if it was a valid JSON. I will try to break this one out so it doesn't look like some black magic.

```
var wordRegExp = /(\w+)/g //g stands for global. Without it, only one match will be returned
var escapedString = str.replace(wordRegExp, '"$1"') //$1 is the match
var myArray = JSON.parse(escapedString)
```